# No Consecutive Spaces RegEx Group PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

```
^([A-Za-z0-9 ]){8,12}
```

How do I turn this into something that can have spaces any where but not consecutively?

Id est:

```
A L L 0 W E D

N O T  A L L 0 W E D # Note two spaces between `not` and `allowed`
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: @user2655603 `^([A-Za-z0-9([ {1}]){8,12}` and things alike.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use lookahead/behind technique, like the following: `'/^([A-Za-z0-9]| (?! )){8,12}/'` . It means we expect A-Z, a-z and 0-9 OR space, but not followed by space. Take a look at the result:

```
$strs = array(
    '12345678',
    'A L L 0 W E D',
    'N O T  A L L 0 W E D' # Note two spaces between `not` and `allowed`
);

$preg = '/^([A-Za-z0-9]| (?! )){8,12}/';

foreach ($strs as $str) {
    var_dump(preg_match($preg, $str));
}

return;
```

It will return:

```
int(1)
int(1)
int(0)
```

Comment: Seems to work great. Could you explain what ` (?! )` exactly does or link to documentation?

Comment: @SAz As i've written in the answer, it means 'space, but not followed by space'. Generally, you specify something (in our case space), but not followed by smth else (in our case - space too). For example, if you need 'foo' not followed by 'bar', you should write 'foo(?!bar)'. You can find more about it at http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.assertions.php .

Comment: Thank you. That clarifies a lot!